# VSCode: [js] This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have updated to Visual Studio Code version 1.23.0 recently and I am starting to see this code hint:

```
[js] This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration.
var _myFunctionName: () => void
```

How can I turn this hint off? I have not found the right setting so far.

Comment: You've showed the type declaration of the function, not the implementation

Comment: What extensions do you have installed, what linters do you have enabled?

Comment: I don't have any extension installed, this is a fresh install. I guess this would be [TypeScript linting](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L3944)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [March 2018 release notes: suggested code actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_suggestion-code-actions-for-javascript-and-typescript)

> Suggestion Code Actions are enabled by default in JavaScript and
>   TypeScript. You can disable them by setting:
>   "`typescript.suggestionActions.enabled": false` or
>   "`javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false`

Comment: "javascript.suggestionActions.enabled": false worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to disable only _certain_ suggestions?