# Why is Visual Studio Code recognizing my function as a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, constructor, jshint

## Description of Issue

I was reviewing my code for one of my projects when I noticed that one of my function's name is coloured green while all of the other functions are yellow.

[image]

When I hover over the function in the `readButton.addEventListener("click", toggleRead);` it says: `Class toggleRead - function toggleRead(e: any): void`

Also, when I hover over the actual function declaration, it says `This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration.ts(80002)`

## Additional Info

I am using the `toggleRead` function to toggle an attribute. The `this` keyword refers to the button that calls the function. It doesn't seem to cause any issues in my program and it is working as intended.

## Question

Am I breaking some kind of code convention that results in this hint, or am I otherwise doing something wrong? Also, why does visual studio think this function is a constructor?

## Similar Issue

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257877/vscode-js-this-constructor-function-may-be-converted-to-a-class-declaration) question on stack overflow but the person asking the question is only interested in turning the hint off. I want to know if I did something wrong.

## Code

```js
readButton.addEventListener("click", toggleRead);
```

```js
// Toggle book read
function toggleRead(e) {
    const bookIndex = getBookIndex(this);
    const bookObject = library.at(bookIndex);
    if (bookObject.read) {
        bookObject.read = false;
        this.setAttribute("is-read", "false");
        this.innerHTML = "Unread";
    } else {
        bookObject.read = true;
        this.setAttribute("is-read", "true");
        this.innerHTML = "Read";
    }
}
```

Comment: A non-member function that uses `this` looks like a constructor. (Because `this` is normally bound to the "thing before the dot", but calling a non-member function is done without a dot, and `this` defaults to the global object.) My guess is that the analyzer doesn't realize that DOM event listeners get a special `this` that is bound to the event that raised the event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is my code bad practice, or just something the analyzer over looked?

Comment: I think it's fine. The analyzer just doesn't realize that it's being used as an event handler. It might be more idiomatic to use `e.currentTarget`, though. Switch to `e.currentTarget` will also avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to post Raymond's recommendation from their comment under my question as this resolved the issue for me:

The solution was to replace `this` with the more idiomatic `e.currentTarget`.

```js
// Toggle book read
function toggleRead(e) {
    const bookIndex = getBookIndex(e.currentTarget);
    const bookObject = library.at(bookIndex);
    if (bookObject.read) {
        bookObject.read = false;
        e.currentTarget.setAttribute("is-read", "false");
        e.currentTarget.innerHTML = "Unread";
    } else {
        bookObject.read = true;
        e.currentTarget.setAttribute("is-read", "true");
        e.currentTarget.innerHTML = "Read";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the analyzer probably marks it as a constructor because of how it's defined + what is inside of it, which resembles how a constructor would be written.

A solution may be to define it using `const` and a lambda expression, as follows.

*Change the first line:*

```
function toggleRead(e) {
```

*to this:*

```
const toggleRead = (e) => {
```

An additional benefit of using lambda notation is that you can use such functions without first calling `bind` on them.
So if you are now doing `this.toggleRead = this.toggleRead.bind(this);` then you can safely remove it because the `this` inside a lambda is by default always the object in which the lambda is being created.

Comment: This doesn't work because you cannot bind `this` in an arrow function, but the handlers expect `this` to be bound to the event source. This limitation is [called out on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#other_notes).